# IndexedDB Performance of Index: Select and Insert

Tags: javascript, performance, indexeddb

## Question 1:

### Q1.1

What is the complexity of IndexedDB (Javascript version) doing select or insert? Whether the indexes are "indexed"? Is it sorted or hashed? For example, when we use IDBKeyRange.only, it is taking O(1), O(log(n)), or O(n) time?

### Q1.2

How about the IDBKeyRange.bound? Is it sorting the index first and then doing the select?

### Q1.3

What is the performance of IDBObjectStore.add()?

## Q1.4

For index.openCursor(), is the index sorted in advance?

## Question 2:

We are using IDBObjectStore.createIndex() to create indexes.
If the answer is yes in Question 1 (which means the indexes are indexed), how to create index with options indexed or not indexed? In other words, I choose some indexes to be sorted or hashed, while others not. Do we have this choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification doesn't mandate performance characteristics. It's reasonable to assume an implementation using a [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), and therefore operations O(log n), but you'd need to test implementations in browsers. If a particular browser performs poorly on common operations, it may be worth reporting it as an issue.

> Q1.1 What is the complexity of IndexedDB (Javascript version) doing
>   select or insert? Whether the indexes are "indexed"? Is it sorted or hashed?

Indexes are sorted. https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#index-construct

> Q1.2 How about the IDBKeyRange.bound? Is it sorting the index first and then doing the select?

The lookup is against the sorted index.

> Q1.3 What is the performance of IDBObjectStore.add()?

Assuming a B-tree, O(log n)

> Q1.4 For index.openCursor(), is the index sorted in advance?

Yes.

Although technically an implementation could create the index lazily -- the specification does not require particular performance or implementation, just that the results are indistinguishable.

> Question 2:... how to create index with options indexed or not indexed? In other words, I choose some indexes to be sorted or hashed, while others not. Do we have this choice?

No - the API doesn't expose such an option.

Comment: For question 2, that means for each index, it has its own sorted table of "pointers" pointing to every items?

Comment: Yes. https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#index-construct defines an index. It's effectively a sorted list of (indexKey,primaryKey) pairs

Comment: Still for question 2, maybe my question is not clarified enough. I mean whether we have the choice to "index" a specific column. The answer should be yes, right? Previously I thought we had to add columns by adding indexes. Now I find that we can add column by adding a json key in each item.

Comment: "...whether we have the choice to "index" a specific column. The answer should be yes, right?" - you can create an index on any property within values which is a valid key. If you store an object such as {a: 123, b: {c: {d: "hello"}}} and you create an index with key path "b.c.d" then there will be an entry in the index with the index key "hello". If thinking of that as columns helps, go for it.

Comment: Is it able to create index with reverse order? I know we can use cursor to read in both directions. However, when the table shows in Chrome's inspect->application->indexeddb, it is only ascending order. Is it able to show in descending order?

Comment: "Is it able to create index with reverse order?" -- no, you use a reverse cursor for this. Custom collation order is not present in the current API 
"Is it able to show in descending order?" -- Chrome's devtools doesn't support that feature.